# How would I ping between two pfsense WAN connections?

Tags: ping

This is my network connection: 
[image]
They both are in vmware workstation, so they are virtual.

I want to ping from the pc to the server. I do not need internet connection, just a ping would be enough. I can ping between pcs and pfsenses, but the WAN connection between pfsenses do not respond. I turned on bogon and private networks in all interfaces. I used static routing like this:

[image]
[image]
I also added firewall rules to allow icmp packets on both interfaces like this: 
[image]
[image]

Here, the pfsenses are in host only mode, so they do not have outside internet connection and they do not need it-a simple ping is enough.

How would I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By design the PFSense FW is doing its job.  Protecting the LAN side, by blocking all traffic.

To talk to a server behind the FW here are 3 ways to do this:

1).  Setup a 2nd IP on the PFSense FW and then a 1:1 NAT forward to the server and route ICMP and other traffic to the server behind the firewall.

2).  Assign the NAT forward for ICMP to the server, not the PFSense FW, then the packet will be forwarded and if the server replies, so will the FW.

3).  Establish a VPN between the two networks then you can freely send traffic from one network to the other.